# MySQL outputs multiple columns per field based on field status

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL(version:5.7) table with the following fields:

```
 account: varchar
 work_status: varchar
 work_details: varchar
```

There are data like this:

```
 account       |   work_status   |   work_details |  
 xxx@gmail.com        work          coding
 xxx@gmail.com       onBusiness    conclude a contract
```

I want to achieve something similar to the following:

```
 account       |   work_status_work   |  work_status_onBusiness |  
 xxx@gmail.com       22                   8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation -

```
select account, 
       count(case when work_status='work' then 1 end) as work_status_work,
       count(case when work_status='onBusiness' then 1 end) as work_status_onBusiness
from tablename
group by account
```